# C# NAudio - Changing audio playback position still plays a small buffer of old position

Tags: c#, wpf, position, mp3, naudio

I am trying to make a basic MP3 player in C# and WPF, along with NAudio. I recently added a slider that tracks the current position in the song as well as allows you to drag it to a different position and upon `Thumb.DragCompleted` it will set the song's position to where you dragged it.

This all works fine and all, except when I make it jump to the new position, it still plays the old position 1/5th or so of a second before changing. This is most noticeable e.g. while the singer is in the middle of singing "aaa", you pause, drag to a point where he sings "ooo", then play again, you will hear "aa-ooo". This just results in it sounding pretty horrible.

So I suppose the audio playback simply has a small 'buffer' remaining that it insists on playing before moving on. Is there any way to clear this buffer? Or am I setting the position wrong?

I am using a `WaveOut waveOutDevice` and an `AudioFileReader audioFileReader`. The slider is called `sldrPlaybackProgress`.
I tried to change position in the song in two different ways already:

First method:

```cs
audioFileReader.CurrentTime = new TimeSpan(0, (int)(Math.Floor(sldrPlaybackProgress.Value / 60)), (int)(Math.Floor(sldrPlaybackProgress.Value % 60)));
```

Second method:

```cs
audioFileReader.Position = (long)(sldrPlaybackProgress.Value * audioFileReader.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond);
```

Both of these individually or even both combined still result in the problem persisting.

Comment: Try to pause, set position, play again.

Comment: I have tried this, still won't work. I even desperately tried to re-initialize both the WaveOut and AudioFileReader, but this produced some weird bugs with the song playing twice - not to mention it's probably not very efficient to do that.

Comment: Just found that WaveOut.Stop(), setting AudioFileReader's position, then starting WaveOut.Play() again WILL fix it. I think this could make for some annoying bugs later in the code if I have some WaveOut.PlaybackStopped event handler, but that's something I'll just have to work around. Thanks for the pause/play idea, got me on the right track :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should call `Stop` when a reposition happens during pause. This will flush any outstanding buffers and. Under the hood `Stop` calls `waveOutStop` and `Pause` calls `waveOutPause`, which doesn't clear any in progress playing buffers.

Comment: Wow, directly from the horse's mouth.Thanks, this helped me keep going...Probably this should be more clear from the demo program (used WinForms)